# Typecasting Variant Array into String or Boolean Array

Tags: vba, excel, casting

I have several named ranges inside my Excel sheet where I store data for VBA Macros between sessions. When loading I need to get that data into multiple arrays (`String` and `Booleans`).

```
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim rg As Range

Set rg = Sheets("Calc").Range("myRange")
arr = rg.Value2
```

How can I typecast `arr()` into a `String` or `Boolean` array for use in my macro?

If I try and use `Variant` arrays instead I get `ByRef argument mismatch errors` on function calls.

Or Is there maybe another way to get the contents of the ranges into an array of other type than `Variant`?

Searching did not yield a result on the latter question.

Comment: For a Boolean, you'd have to populate the array in a loop. For strings, as long as it's a one row or column range, you can do it with a little messing about, but looping is still simpler.

Comment: Can't you cast it to a string etc when passing to your function? Something like `CStr(arr(1, 1))` - or do you pass the entire array into your function?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way of doing that other than manually casting in a loop. Wouldn't it be easier to test for type within the function and just pass the Variant: `If VarType(v) = vbBoolean Then`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to declare your array as an array of Strings or Booleans, simply like this :

```
Dim arr() as String
Dim arr() as Boolean
```

It works also for functions btw.

And if you can't load the whole range because of a type mismatch, load this in an temporary Variant Array and then ReDim your String or Boolean array to match and loop on everything and use conversion functions : `CBool`, `CStr`, `CInt`, `CDbl`, ...

Comment: I was trying to avoid looping but it seems to be the easiest way. Wouldn't it be easier to loop over the range right of the bat instead of loading into a variant array first?

Comment: You may test it, but loading an array from a range and working on the array is pretty fast, although reading info in a specific cell isn't that long but not really efficient. You can check the time spent by code by setting up a variable `StartTime = Timer` and at the end : `MsgBox "Done in " & Timer - StartTime & " seconds"`

Comment: @ChrisUnbroken Glad I could help, if I can just ask that you upvote my answer, it would be nice (I'm working on my "Refiner" badge). Enjoy SO ;)

Comment: I would have done so before but I only just passed the 15 Reputation required to do so :) Thanks again

Comment: I know I upvoted your 2 questions so that you can! ;)
And that's why I poke you afterwards^^
Have a nice journey here! Thx for the vote! ;)